# How to get expand output for powershell cmdlet get-adtrust?

Tags: powershell, dns, enumeration

The powershell command get-aduser outputs a result similar to

```
DistinguishedName  : CN=kw.k.com,CN=System,DC=my,DC=kw,DC=k,DC=com
Name               : kw.k.com
ObjectClass        : trustedDomain
ObjectGuid         : 4bbec03e-b031-4b54-9d6c-2e3e812b6e66
PropertyNames      : {Direction, DisallowTransivity, DistinguishedName, ForestTransitive, IntraForest, IsTreeParent, IsTreeRoot,
                     Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SelectiveAuthentication, SIDFilteringForestAware, SIDFilteringQuarantined,
                     Source, Target, TGTDelegation, TrustAttributes, TrustedPolicy, TrustingPolicy, TrustType, UplevelOnly,
                     UsesAESKeys, UsesRC4Encryption}
AddedProperties    : {}
RemovedProperties  : {}
ModifiedProperties : {}
PropertyCount      : 23
```

I would like to view the values for each property in 'PropertyNames'. How can this be achieved ?

Comment: `... | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get and or expand properties to get there values in a few ways. This is a well-documented use case, and not specific to this cmdlet. What iRon shows and the below depending on how much you need to see.

Try...

Dot referencing

> [Microsoft Docs | PowerShell Help files : About Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_properties?view=powershell-7)
>
> Property values
>
> Although every object of a specific type has the same
>   properties, the values of those properties describe the particular
>   object. For example, every FileInfo object has a CreationTime
>   property, but the value of that property differs for each file.
>
> The most common way to get the values of the properties of an object
>   is to use the dot method. Type a reference to the object, such as a
>   variable that contains the object, or a command that gets the object.
>   Then, type a dot (.) followed by the property name.

```
(Get-ADTrust -Identity 'corp.contoso.com').PropertyNames
```

Or using [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7) and expanding collection properties

```
Get-ADTrust -Identity 'corp.contoso.com' | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty PropertyNames
```

Comment: Just a typo in the last line: change `PropertNames` to `PropertyNames`. Sorry, not enough rep to [do it by myself](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26017902).